# Autofac ServiceLocator issue in release v2.4.5.724

Tags: autofac

I have just upgraded to MVC 3 and likewise need to upgrade Autofac.

The following code was working, but now fails with this error -

> This resolve operation has already
>   ended. When registering components
>   using lambdas, the IComponentContext
>   'c' parameter to the lambda cannot be
>   stored.  Instead, either resolve
>   IComponentContext again from 'c', or
>   resolve a Func<> based factory to
>   create subsequent components from.

```
    public static IServiceLocator Locator;

    public class ServiceA : IServiceA
    {
    }

    public interface IServiceA
    {
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestAutofacServiceLocator()
    {
        // This resolve operation has already ended. When registering components using lambdas, the IComponentContext 'c' parameter to the lambda cannot be stored. 
        // Instead, either resolve IComponentContext again from 'c', or resolve a Func<> based factory to create subsequent components from.
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<ServiceA>().As<IServiceA>();

        builder.Register(c => Locator = new AutofacServiceLocator(c)).As<IServiceLocator>().SingleInstance();

        var container = builder.Build();

        container.Resolve<IServiceLocator>();
        var x = Locator.GetInstance<IServiceA>();
        Assert.NotNull(x);
    }
```

How should I resgister IServiceLocator?

I looked at the answer to question [autofac registration issue in release v2.4.5.724](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383888/autofac-registration-issue-in-release-v2-4-5-724) but I'm still confused.

Answer (score 1):

I really should have read Nick's error message, the answer was in the message.

Fixed !!

`builder.Register(c => Locator = new AutofacServiceLocator(c.Resolve()))
                .As().SingleInstance();`

Comment: Cool stuff :) ... In MVC3, you might consider dropping your custom service locator and use `DependencyResolver.Current` instead.